# Linux unicode/umlauts in URL

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, unicode

We have a website, where some pictures name using unicode, e.g. `wildkräuter2_big.jpg`.

Problem is - when anybody trying to access it - Apache 2.4 returns a 404 error:

`$ curl -r 0-99 http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/wildkräuter2_big.jpg`

in Apache's log:

> 40.***.***.168 - - [30/Jun/2016:13:27:36 +0000] "GET /wp-content/uploads/2014/11/wildkr%C3%A4uter2_big.jpg HTTP/1.0" *404*
>   22295 "-" "curl/7.35.0"`

`%C3%A4` here - is an *ä*, as [Deutsch - Unicode Tabelle](http://www.webmaster-seo.com/unicode/language/var/de/) says.

If execute `GET` with `%C3%A4` - it will not work.
If execute `GET` with an `a%CC%88` - it *will* work:

`$ curl -r 0-99 http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/wildkra%CC%88uter2_big.jpg
����▒ExifII��Duckyd���http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/<?xpacket begin="`

I'm not sure - from where I got an `a%CC%88` code - but it works.

So, two "same" URLs:

http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/wildkra%CC%88uter2_big.jpg - this works

http://domain.tld/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/wildkr%C3%A4uter2_big.jpg - this does not work.

Both `a%CC%88` and `%C3%A4` means same - an *ä* letter.

This site was migrated from other agency and we haven't information about its setup.

Our current server works under Ubuntu 14.04, with `LANG=de` (`apache2` was restarted after `LANG` was changed, but not whole Linux server) as `locale` and `ext4` filesystem:

```
# su -s /bin/bash www-data

$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=de
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de"
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="de"
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="de"
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: Ignore my other comment, had a brainfart and forgot that the U+ codepoints had to be calculated from UTF-8.  %CC%88 is U+0308, which is combining diaresis, which means "add an umlaut to the previous character".  Thus "a%CC%88" *looks* the same as "%C3%A4" but the actual bytes in the filename on the disk is different, so the first one is not found.  I'm not putting an answer since I don't know what to tell you to fix this, other than be consistent in Unicode [normalization](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2013/01/why-unicode-normalization-matters.html)